# Proof of congruence with mod 3

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

Ok so I've tried making this one work for a while and keep getting stuck.  I have the following:
Prove: ($x^2$ is congruent to $x\mod3$) $\iff$ ($x$ is not congruent to $2\mod3$).

So I know it is bi-conditional and needs both directions to be proven.  In one direction, I took the contrapositive and said: If ($x$ is congruent to $2\mod3$), then ($x^2$ is not congruent to $x\mod3$).

So:
$x=3k+2$ where $k$ is an integer.

then $x^2=9k^2+12k+4$

$(x^2)-x=9k^2+9k+2=3(3k^2+3k)+2.$

So I think, (not sure as I'm really new to this) that since we can't "factor completely" without a remainder of $2$, then we have no congruence and the original statement is correct.  Now, making this go the other way is where I'm stuck because how do you manipulate this around if you can't work with just a single $x$ and thus just $x$'s congruence?  Contradiction doesn't seem to work, and using contrapositive again only lets you assume $x^2$ is not congruent to $x\mod3$ and again, you can't work with just $x$.  Again I'm pretty new to this but any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

$\implies$ If $x \equiv 2 \mod 3$, then $2^2 = 4 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $x^2$ not congruent to $x$.

$\impliedby$ When $x \ncong 2 \mod 3$ the cases $0^2 \equiv 0 \mod 3$ and $1^2 \equiv 1\mod 3$ shows that $x^2 \equiv x \mod 3$.

*Edit:*

$\implies$ (Contrapositive). If $x \equiv 2 \mod 3$. Let $x = 2 + 3k$ for some $k$. Then $$x^2 = 4 + 12k + 9k^2 = 1 + 3(1 + 4k + 3k^2) = 1 + 3m$$ 
Therefore, $x^2 = 2^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $x^2$ is not congruent to $x$.

$\impliedby$ When $x \ncong 2 \mod 3$, we examine the two cases:

$0^2 \equiv 0 \mod 3$ since $x = 3k \implies x^2 = 3(3k^2) = 3m$ with $m = 3k^2$.

$1^2 \equiv 1\mod 3$ since $x=1 + 3k \implies x^2 = 1 + 6k + 9k^2 = 1 + 3m$ with $m = 2k+3k^2$.

Therefore, $x^2 \equiv x \mod 3$ holds when $x \ncong 2 \mod 3$.

Comment: Umm... could you explain a bit of what you did there?

Comment: @billyredface88 Edited.

Comment: Ok so let me see if I got this: basically you can only have a remainder of 3m+1, or a 3m+0 that satisfies both congruences so, trying to satisfy a remainder of 2 does not work (in both directions) and it looks like I was thinking about it the wrong way in the part I tried to get working.  So when saying not congruent in a situation like this, it's just whatever other possible remainder integers exist that are less than what is not allowed?  Like in this case just 0,1 are the only options.

Comment: Yes,  the integers modulo division by $3$ partitions it into three equivalence classes: $\overline{0} = \{\dots , -3, 0,3,6,\dots\}, \overline{1} = \{ \dots, -2, 1, 4, \dots\}, \overline{2} = \{ \dots, -1, 2, 5, \dots \}$.  So, if we assume it's not in one of them, it must be in one of the other two.